# different calculation results using bc in script and console

Tags: bash, bc

In script i'm writing now i need some decimal calculations so i decided to use `bc`. I'm not familiar with this tool so forgive me if the question is trivial.
When i use console and type in :

> set r_m=`echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l`

then `echo "$r_m"` it gives me:
`19.849870`
($pd_f and $d_f were declared 1.129 and 1.126 respectively before, oh and $fr_numb=18)

but(!) using the same lines in bash script:

> r_m=`echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l`

gives me:
`.033022`

Why?

UPDATE
I enclosed everything after `=` in backticks. I didn't know how to use them in blockquote earlier.

The shell is bash 2.05

Comment: What shell uses your *console*? If I type your example, it gives me `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` (four times). So, what values have the variables `$pd_f`, `$d_f`, `$fr_numb` ?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: I've updated the question. It shouldn't give you syntax errors now. And as i said, those variables were set earlier and are simple numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script

```
#!/bin/bash

pd_f=1.129
d_f=1.126
fr_numb=18

r_m=`echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l`

echo $r_m
```

outputs 19.849870 on

```
GNU bash, Version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

just like the output is when typing it in on a (bash-driven) console. Maybe you need to export the variables before calling your script, if they are not defined in it, but only in the surrounding shell?

Comment: If i run the equation from console i set variables in console before calculations. If i run it inside the script i'm setting $pd_f, $d_f and fr_numb before also.

Comment: Oh, i rechecked it once more and found out that fr_numb was badly declared. It's nice now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I get the result .033022 when `fr_numb=0`.

By the way, your interactive command is apparently being run in csh. You should make sure that your script has the following as its first line if you want to make sure it's being run by Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Also, use some spaces and line continuation to make your formula more readable.

```
#!/bin/bash
pd_f=1.129
d_f=1.126
fr_numb=18
fr_numb=0
r_m=$(echo "scale=6; \
    $pd_f*$d_f * (1 / sqrt(3)) + \
    ($fr_numb - 1) * ( \
        $pd_f * $d_f * (1 / sqrt(3)) + \
        $pd_f * $d_f * 0.5 * \
        ( \
            s(3.14159265 * 30 / 180) / c(3.14159265 * 30 / 180) \
        ) \
     ) + \
     0.4 " | bc -l)
```

By the way, when posting a question, post variable assignments so they can be easily copied so your setup can be reproduced rather than in a prose style like "($pd_f and $d_f were declared 1.129 and 1.126 respectively before, oh and $fr_numb=18)" which requires heavy editing to make usable.

Comment: Thanks for those pieces of advice, i'll try to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 variables set in your shell, for example:

```
pd_f=1
d_f=2
fr_numb=3
```

and you run the original command:

```
set r_m=`echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l`
```

then you end up with `$1` set to `r_m=5.018798` (and all other positional parameters are undefined).  That's because in `bash` and all other Bourne shell derivatives, the `set` statement is used to adjust shell options or to set the meanings of the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, ... etc (but not `$0`).

If you don't have values for the three variables, you get syntax errors diagnosed by `bc`.

Note, especially, that the original command does not set the variable `r_m`; that would only set the variable in a C shell or C shell derivative.  The shell variable `$r_m` is completely unaffected by the `set` statement.  What you saw as a result in `$r_m` was whatever happened to be left over in the variable from your previous experimentation.

On the other hand, when you run:

```
r_m=`echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l`
```

then you are assigning to the variable `r_m`.

Answer (score 0):

enclose your command with $()

```
r_m=$(echo "scale=6; $pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+($fr_numb-1)*($pd_f*$d_f*(1/sqrt(3))+$pd_f*$d_f*0.5*(s(3.14159265*30/180)/c(3.14159265*30/180)))+0.4"|bc -l)
```

Comment: well the truth is that it is enclosed in `` but i didn't know how to insert backticks into blockquotes. $() didn't help.

Comment: $() is easier to type (ans show) here on Stackoverflow, which is a reason to use it. Another reason is that it is easier to see the nesting, when you have more than one level. It does nothing for your problem here, though.